# How To Call A Method After A Certain Period

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL database running on my localhost. To this database I have JDBC-connection. Over a RESTful WebService a softwareagent puts results into this database. I implemented a garbage collector in Java and want to execute that garbage collector after a certain period. My aim is that I do not have too many entries in the table.

The Garbage Collector looks as follows:

```
public void collectGarbageResults() {
    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ResultSet rs = this.execQuery("SELECT * FROM results");
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            if ( (System.currentTimeMillis()) - (Timestamp.valueOf(rs.getString("tmstmp")).getTime()) > Long.parseLong(appconfigs.get("resultstableactuality")) ) {
                ids.add(rs.getInt("id"));
            }
        }

        for (Integer i : ids) {
            this.deleteResultsWhereId(i);
        }           
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The method I call looks as follows:

```
private void deleteResultsWhereId(int id) {
    retint = this.updateQuery("DELETE FROM results WHERE id=" + id + ";");
}
```

I am using JSF in an Eclipse's Dynamic Web Project and these methods are implemented in a managed bean. I am going to store the interval in an XML-file which I use for my application's configuration. Over the variable appconfigs I call the method 'get' and ask for the node containing my interval.

**Now my question:**

*How can I call the method of the garbage collector after a certain period in my WebApp?*

If you have any questions do not hesitate to comment.

> My Solution :

```
@WebListener
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener{

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        long delayToStart   = 0;
        long numberOfUnits  = 60;
        TimeUnit tu = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ExecuteGarbageCollector(), delayToStart, numberOfUnits, tu);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

The class I call implements Runnable as follows:

```
public class ExecuteGarbageCollector implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DAO dao = new DAO();
        dao.collectGarbageResults();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54)  or [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Quartz has a lot of facilities, but [If you choose ScheduledExecutorService you don't have to add any new dependencies to your project.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and as you just want this scheduled task, it's simple.

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);
```

Take a look at some comments about both in: [Quartz vs. ScheduledExecutorService in Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726088/quartz-vs-scheduledexecutorservice-in-java-web-application)

Comment: I accepted your answer because both options work. I don't know yet how to include them into my existing application, but I am sure this will be soon, owing to your last link. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out a scheduler library. You can use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) for example.
2. [Call Java from MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/execution-of-a-java-program-by-a-trigger). You could either have this kicked off by a job or trigger
3. Just stick to SQL and ignore running this in Java. Probably the easiest if you are good at SQL. Then you can encapsulate this in a SPROC or trigger.

It's your choice whether this should live in your web-app or in your database. I've used both methods for executing timed SQL calls and tend to prefer the code oriented approach

Comment: Unfortunately I am not this good at SQL. But I am going to use Quartz or the ScheduledExecutorService. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

The actual question could have well been how to call a function after a specific interval of time? 
Take a look at :
[How to call a method after some specific interval of time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858573/how-to-call-a-method-after-some-specific-interval-of-time-in-java)
and
[java: run a function after a specific number of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258066/java-run-a-function-after-a-specific-number-of-seconds)